# How to make a time rotation in Qsharp like in Quirk spinning gates?

Tags: quantum-gate, q#

Qsharp have Rx Ry and Rz gates for rotation, but I need to apply a gate that leaves the Qbuit rotating continuosly like in Quirk spinning gates.
https://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22%3A%5B%5B%22H%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B%22X%5Et%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22Chance%22%5D%2C%5B%22ZDetectControlReset%22%5D%5D%7D
This is because later I will entangled it with another Qbuit, so both will be rotating, to try to sincronize meseaures

Answer (score 5):

Your question suggests you want to try an experiment that would only work if the [no communication theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-communication_theorem) wasn't a thing. So... just be aware of that.

In Quirk, the time-based gates are not continuously twisting the same qubit over time. Instead, every time a frame is drawn, the current time determines what the one thing the gate will do to the qubits is. When you see the state display to the right rotating, you are seeing a series of outputs that were operated on in slightly different ways (not one state being iteratively operated on and changed).

As such, the simplest way to emulate the time-based gates in Q# is to create an operation that include a time parameter, run simulations with a variety of time values, and look at the results.